# How to create pandas dataframes with more than 2 dimensions?

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe

**I want to be able to create `n-dimensional` dataframes.**  I've heard of a method for 3D dataframes using `panels` in `pandas` but, if possible, I would like to extend the dimensions past 3 dims by combining different datasets into a *super dataframe*

I tried this but I cannot figure out how to use these methods with my test dataset -> 
[Constructing 3D Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290495/constructing-3d-pandas-dataframe)

Also, this did not help for my case -> [Pandas Dataframe or Panel to 3d numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478297/pandas-dataframe-or-panel-to-3d-numpy-array)

I made a random test dataset with arbitrary axis data trying to mimic a real situation; there are 3 axis (i.e. patients, years, and samples).  I tried adding a bunch of dataframes to a list and then making a dataframe with that but it didn't work :(  I even tried a `panel` as in the 2nd link above but I couldn't get it to work either.

**Does anybody know how to create a N-dimensional pandas dataframe w/ labels?**

The first way I tried:

```
#Reproducibility
np.random.seed(1618033)

#Set 3 axis labels/dims
axis_1 = np.arange(2000,2010) #Years
axis_2 = np.arange(0,20) #Samples
axis_3 = np.array(["patient_%d" % i for i in range(0,3)]) #Patients

#Create random 3D array to simulate data from dims above
A_3D = np.random.random((years.size, samples.size, len(patients))) #(10, 20, 3)

#Create empty list to store 2D dataframes (axis_2=rows, axis_3=columns) along axis_1
list_of_dataframes=[]

#Iterate through all of the year indices
for i in range(axis_1.size):
    #Create dataframe of (samples, patients)
    DF_slice = pd.DataFrame(A_3D[i,:,:],index=axis_2,columns=axis_3)
    list_of_dataframes.append(DF_slice)
#     print(DF_slice) #preview of the 2D dataframes "slice" of the 3D array
#           patient_0  patient_1  patient_2
#      0    0.727753   0.154701   0.205916
#      1    0.796355   0.597207   0.897153
#      2    0.603955   0.469707   0.580368
#      3    0.365432   0.852758   0.293725
#      4    0.906906   0.355509   0.994513
#      5    0.576911   0.336848   0.265967
#     ...
#     19   0.583495   0.400417   0.020099

# DF_3D = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dataframes,index=axis_2, columns=axis_1)
# Error
# Shape of passed values is (1, 10), indices imply (10, 20)
```

2nd way I tried:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(axis_3,columns=axis_2) 
#Error:
#Shape of passed values is (1, 3), indices imply (20, 3)

# p={}
# for i in axis_1:
#     p[i]=DF
# panel= pd.Panel(p)
```

I could do something like this I guess, but I really like `pandas` and would rather use one of their methods if one exists:

```
#Set data for query
query_year = 2007
query_sample = 15
query_patient = "patient_1"

#Index based on query
A_3D[
     (axis_1 == query_year).argmax(),
     (axis_2 == query_sample).argmax(),
     (axis_3 == query_patient).argmax()
]
#0.1231212416981845
```

It would be awesome to access the data in this way:

```
DF_3D[query_year][query_sample][query_patient]
#Where DF_3D[query_year] would give a list of 2D arrays (row=sample, col=patient)
# DF_3D[query_year][query_sample] would give a 1D vector/list of patient data for a particular year, of a particular sample.
# and DF_3D[query_year][query_sample][query_patient] would be a particular sample of a particular patient of a particular year
```

Comment: You are probably better off using two dimensions, but using a MultiIndex to represent your additional dimensions.

Comment: Would the `MultiIndex` axis be my years axis (`axis_1`) ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than using an n-dimensional Panel, you are probably better off using a two dimensional representation of data, but using MultiIndexes for the index, column or both.

For example:

```
np.random.seed(1618033)

#Set 3 axis labels/dims
years = np.arange(2000,2010) #Years
samples = np.arange(0,20) #Samples
patients = np.array(["patient_%d" % i for i in range(0,3)]) #Patients

#Create random 3D array to simulate data from dims above
A_3D = np.random.random((years.size, samples.size, len(patients))) #(10, 20, 3)

# Create the MultiIndex from years, samples and patients.
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, samples, patients])

# Create sample data for each patient, and add the MultiIndex.
patient_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(midx), 3), index = midx)

>>> patient_data.head()
                         0         1         2
2000 0 patient_0 -0.128005  0.371413 -0.078591
       patient_1 -0.378728 -2.003226 -0.024424
       patient_2  1.339083  0.408708  1.724094
     1 patient_0 -0.997879 -0.251789 -0.976275
       patient_1  0.131380 -0.901092  1.456144
```

Once you have data in this form, it is relatively easy to juggle it around.  For example:

```
>>> patient_data.unstack(level=0).head()  # Years.
                    0                                                                                              ...            2                                                                                          
                 2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005      2006      2007      2008      2009    ...         2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005      2006      2007      2008      2009
0 patient_0 -0.128005  0.051558  1.251120  0.666061 -1.048103  0.259231  1.535370  0.156281 -0.609149  0.360219    ...    -0.078591 -2.305314 -2.253770  0.865997  0.458720  1.479144 -0.214834 -0.791904  0.800452  0.235016
  patient_1 -0.378728 -0.117470 -0.306892  0.810256  2.702960 -0.748132 -1.449984 -0.195038  1.151445  0.301487    ...    -0.024424  0.114843  0.143700  1.732072  0.602326  1.465946 -1.215020  0.648420  0.844932 -1.261558
  patient_2  1.339083 -0.915771  0.246077  0.820608 -0.935617 -0.449514 -1.105256 -0.051772 -0.671971  0.213349    ...     1.724094  0.835418  0.000819  1.149556 -0.318513 -0.450519 -0.694412 -1.535343  1.035295  0.627757
1 patient_0 -0.997879 -0.242597  1.028464  2.093807  1.380361  0.691210 -2.420800  1.593001  0.925579  0.540447    ...    -0.976275  1.928454 -0.626332 -0.049824 -0.912860  0.225834  0.277991  0.326982 -0.520260  0.788685
  patient_1  0.131380  0.398155 -1.671873 -1.329554 -0.298208 -0.525148  0.897745 -0.125233 -0.450068 -0.688240    ...     1.456144 -0.503815 -1.329334  0.475751 -0.201466  0.604806 -0.640869 -1.381123  0.524899  0.041983
```

In order to select the data, please refere to the docs for [MultiIndexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing).

Comment: awesome, this part essentially makes it 4D `np.random.randn(len(midx), 3)`!  The unstacking order gets a little confusing on how the index is formed `#level=0: index = (sample,patient); col = (data,year)
#level=1: index = (year,patient); col = (data,sample)
#level=2: index = (year,sample); col = (data, patient)`

Comment: Shouldn't your `A_3D` be used instead of `np.random.randn(len(midx), 3)`?  It is defined, but never used in your (otherwise clear) example.

Answer (score 6):

You should consider using `xarray` instead. From their [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/pandas.html):

> Panel, pandas’ data structure for 3D arrays, was always a second class data structure compared to the Series and DataFrame. To allow pandas developers to focus more on its core functionality built around the DataFrame, **pandas removed Panel in favor of directing users who use multi-dimensional arrays to xarray**.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I've been using xarray since this post.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach (to [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411802/alexander)) that is derived from the structure of the input data is:

```
np.random.seed(1618033)

#Set 3 axis labels/dims
years = np.arange(2000,2010) #Years
samples = np.arange(0,20) #Samples
patients = np.array(["patient_%d" % i for i in range(0,3)]) #Patients

#Create random 3D array to simulate data from dims above
A_3D = np.random.random((years.size, samples.size, len(patients))) #(10, 20, 3)

# Reshape data to 2 dimensions
maj_dim = 1
for dim in A_3D.shape[:-1]:
    maj_dim = maj_dim*dim
new_dims = (maj_dim, A_3D.shape[-1])
A_3D = A_3D.reshape(new_dims)

# Create the MultiIndex from years, samples and patients.
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, samples])
# Note that Cartesian product order is the same as the 
# C-order used by default in ``reshape``.

# Create sample data for each patient, and add the MultiIndex.
patient_data = pd.DataFrame(data = A_3D, 
                            index = midx,
                            columns = patients)

>>>> patient_data.head()

        patient_0  patient_1  patient_2
2000 0   0.727753   0.154701   0.205916
     1   0.796355   0.597207   0.897153
     2   0.603955   0.469707   0.580368
     3   0.365432   0.852758   0.293725
     4   0.906906   0.355509   0.994513
```