# Storing 3-dimensional data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I'm trying to understand how to manipulate data with pandas DataFrames. I searched for similar questions but I don't see any satisfying my exact need. Please point me to the correct post if this is a duplicate.

So I have multiple DataFrames with the exact same shape, columns and index. How do I combine them with labels so I can easily access the data with any column/index/label?

E.g. after the setup below, how do I put df1 and df2 into one DataFrame and label them with the names 'df1' and 'df2', so I can access data in a way like df['A']['df1']['b'], and get number of rows of df?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'], index=['a', 'b'])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=['A', 'B'], index=['a', 'b'])
>>> df1
   A  B
a  1  2
b  3  4
>>> df2
   A  B
a  5  6
b  7  8
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `MultiIndex DataFrame` is answer created by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('df1','df2'))
print (df)
       A  B
df1 a  1  2
    b  3  4
df2 a  5  6
    b  7  8
```

Then for basic select is possible use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.xs('df1'))
   A  B
a  1  2
b  3  4
```

And for select index and columns together use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['df1', 'b'], 'A'])
3
```

---

Another possible solution is use [panels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel).

But in newer versions of pandas is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dsintro-deprecate-panel).

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes it looks like MultiIndex DataFrame is what I need. Is it possible to convert df['A'] into a 2D DataFrame with ['a', 'b'] as index and ['df1', 'df2'] as columns?

Comment: I think yes, only add `axis=1` like `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('df1','df2'), axis=1)`

Comment: and then select by `idx = pd.IndexSlice`
`print (df.loc['b',idx['df1', 'A']])`

Comment: Or `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=('df1','df2')).unstack(0)` ? and then `print (df.xs('A', axis=1))` ?

Comment: @jezrael hi jezrael I m trying to do the same here concatenating through loop many pds. how can I properly concat the keys as well? I tried making a list I gradually append, but returns "Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels" (which makes sense actually..)

Answer (score 0):

Using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/pandas.html) is recommended, as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67882820/6179774) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431068/6179774) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56460509) similar questions have suggested. Since pandas Panels were deprecated in favour of xarray.